# QGIS - Alignment HTML-Labels

Tags: qgis, html

I want to label areas in an atlas. In my case, these should represent the district, municipality, cadastral area, and plot (in italics). Since the plot should be displayed in italics, I'm using HTML tags here. The text elements are in a point layer because, in repetitions across individual sheets, the higher-level elements like district or municipality should be omitted. So, I've done some manual work here.
I have the following issue: When I try to place the texts with a leader line on narrow areas, unfortunately, the left alignment of the texts in the labeling disappears. Can anyone help me figure out how to force left alignment in HTML labels?

Here is a picture[image]

My labeling code looks like this `CASE WHEN "landkreis" IS NOT NULL AND "gemeinde" IS NOT NULL  THEN 'Kreis ' || "landkreis" ||  '<p>'  || 'Gemeinde ' || "gemeinde" ||  '<p>'  ||'Gemarkung ' ||  "Gemarkung" ||  '<p>'  || '<i>'  ||'Flur ' ||  "flur"  || '<i>' WHEN "landkreis" IS NULL AND "gemeinde" IS NOT NULL  THEN 'Gemeinde ' || "gemeinde" ||  '<p>'  ||'Gemarkung ' ||  "Gemarkung" ||  '<p>'  || '<i>'  ||'Flur ' ||  "flur"  || '<i>' WHEN "landkreis" IS NULL AND "gemeinde" IS NULL  THEN 'Gemarkung ' ||  "Gemarkung" ||  '<p>'  || '<i>'  ||'Flur ' ||  "flur"  || '<i>' END`

I am using QGIS 3.28.8